# Detect site login url in Application_End

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, quartz.net

I have this entry in web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="pingUrl" value="http://examplesite.com/login.aspx"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I have the below code in Global.asax.cs to automatically start the IIS when it is recycle

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string pingUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pingUrl"];
            WebClient http = new WebClient();
            string Result = http.DownloadString(pingUrl);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

My Question is **can I detect the application forms authentication login page url in Application_End method some how**? Instead of reading entry from `<appSettings/>`

Note: I am using Quartz.Net in my MVC4 application and it is stop working when IIS recycle. I read [IIS app pool recycle + quartz scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140597/iis-app-pool-recycle-quartz-scheduling) and many SO links but no use. We use external hosting provider, so we dont have a control of changing a physical config file.

After reading  http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/May/10/Forcing-an-ASPNET-Application-to-stay-alive I decided to go with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MSDN docs on [`FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you have your forms authentication set up in web.config's `<authentication>` element, and you have the "loginURL" populated there, then the property mentioned above should have the information you're looking for.

Comment: It gives `/~/Home/Index` not the fully qualified url to use in a `WebClient.DownloadString` method

Comment: @Billa So you're almost there =)  You just need to build the URL from there.  There are some great answers on how to do that here: [How do I turn a relative URL into a full URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126242/how-do-i-turn-a-relative-url-into-a-full-url)

Comment: The problem is will not be have an access to Request object in Application_End, since this will be called when IIS is recycling and there wont be any url request made :(

Comment: @Billa I think the best thing you can do, then, is code it in your gloabl.asax function as a `const string`.  Since you can't add appSettings and whatnot.

Comment: Also, @Billa - it sounds like Forms Auth is not set up properly in web.config, if your LoginURL is set to the homepage.

Comment: I have the forms authentication setup and that why I am getting relative url. We will be hosting this application in many servers and of course we can't hard code the value in global.asax.cs.